# Why is static const char * template struct member not initialized

Tags: c++, templates, clang, constexpr, visual-c++-2015

I have some C++11 template code I am trying to port to Visual C++ Compiler 2015. The original code works just fine, however I need to rewrite it to work around issues with constexpr.

**[The original code (simplified example)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WDLbHRgchibRGwv3)**

```
#include <iostream>

struct String
{
    static constexpr const char * value{ "STRING" };
};

template<typename Base>
class Derived
{
public:
    static constexpr const char * value{ Base::value };
};

template<typename BarType>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr const char * value{ BarType::value };
};

using Bar = Derived<String>;
using FooBar = Foo<Bar>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "FooBar::value = " << FooBar::value << std::endl;
}
```

This prints:

```
FooBar::value = STRING
```

However, when I rewrite, some static variables are not initialized. Even though it compiles just fine.

**[The ported code (not working)](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ur1YLTICHKmv6R2T)**

```
#include <iostream>

struct String
{
    static const char * value;
};
const char * String::value = "STRING";

template<typename Base>
class Derived
{
public:
    static const char * value;
};
template<typename Base>
const char * Derived<Base>::value = { Base::value };

template<typename BarType>
struct Foo
{
    static const char * value;
};
template<typename BarType>
const char * Foo<BarType>::value = { BarType::value };

using Bar = Derived<String>;
using FooBar = Foo<Bar>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "FooBar::value = " << FooBar::value << std::endl;
}
```

This prints:

```
// nothing (Segmentation fault)
```

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I fix / work around it?

This can be reproduced in Clang and Visual-C++, however GCC prints `FooBar::value = STRING` also in second example.

**Update: [Working solution](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ur1YLTICHKmv6R2T)**

As suggested by @serge-ballesta. I prefere this solution since it is very similar to the original code. Easily applied and easily removed again when constexpr members are added to VS.

Comment: Why is _what_ happening? Is [the output `STRING`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21f5265df51c0047) not what you expected?

Comment: Someone edited away the link to the NOT-working code. Ill fix. STRING is expected.

Comment: explicitly instantiating the two classes with `template class Derived<String>; template struct Foo<Derived<String>>;` before usings [solves the segfault](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fkZHNjXNrMA1gAO8)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe the output [nothing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d3bd56905266171) was not what OP expected.

Comment: @Mathias Yes, I edited away the link because the code should be **in the question**. As should, you know, the actual description of problematic behavior.

Comment: @Barry: From where did you get that version of the code?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I know but Foo is supposed to be a library and String and Derived (and other structs) are in the original code part of detail namespace. I would like to keep the one liner interface and no macros.

Comment: @Barry, agree! But link should be there as well to save all readers from compiling.

Comment: I think is a bug somehow the compiler fails to correctly instantiate `Derived<String>`.

Comment: @101010, Both Clang and Visual-C++ shows this behavior. However GCC does not segfault. Unlikely to be a bug in two compiler.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit From the link. I just copied/pasted

Comment: Pretty sure this is undefined behaviour wrt static initialization ordering.

Comment: @Barry: I click on the link and see different code. You cannot have copy/pasted.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Only `template class Derived<String>;` seems works fine. It force the compiler to initialize `Derived<String>::value` before initializing `Foo<Derived<String>>::value`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The 2nd link? It's definitely the same code.

Comment: @Barry: No, it's _not_!!! `const char * Derived<Base>::value = { Base::value };` vs `const char * Derived<Base>::value = Base::value ;` for a start

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, you're talking about the link I commented up there^? It's the same code, I just deleted the `{}`s.

Comment: @Barry: ..... which made the program _different_ and _completely_ changed the output.....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It did no such thing... adding the `{}`s back gives me the exact same behavior... printing nothing.

Comment: @Barry: My very first comment here contains a link to a live demonstration that contradicts your claim.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Undefined behavior is undefined. gcc did one thing, clang did another.

Comment: @Barry: Ooh just noticed - different compiler though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue comes from [basic.start.init]:

> Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is *unordered* if the variable is an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization

The initializations of `Derived<Base>::value` and `Foo<BarType>::value` are not static initialization - because the right-hand side is not a constant expression. That makes it dynamic initialization. Since the variables are template specializations, the initializations are *unordered* - that is, there is no explicitly defined ordering for the two `value`s.

Thus, we have two possible orderings. The valid one:

```
Derived<Base>::value ==> 0
Foo<BarType>::value ==> 0
Derived<Base>::value ==> Base::value
Foo<BarType>::value ==> BarType::value
```

And the invalid one:

```
Derived<Base>::value ==> 0
Foo<BarType>::value ==> 0
Foo<BarType>::value ==> BarType::value
Derived<Base>::value ==> Base::value
```

If `Derived<Base>::value` is initialized first, then `Foo<BarType>::value` will point to `"STRING"`. Otherwise, if the latter is initialized first, it will be initialized to `0`. The segmentation fault you're seeing results from trying to stream a null character pointer.

Answer (score 1):

@Barry gave the why of the problem.

A possible work around would be force the initialization order. As `String` is not a templated class, `String::value` will be correctly initialized (staticly) before dynamic initialization takes place.

I can imagine 2 ways:

1. Add an explicit init method to `Foo` instead of depending on automatic dynamic initialization:

   ```
   ...
   template<typename BarType>
   struct Foo
   {
       static const char * value;
           static void init() {
               Foo::value = BarType::value;
           }
   };

   template<typename BarType>
   const char * Foo<BarType>::value;

   using Bar = Derived<String>;
   using FooBar = Foo<Bar>;

   int main()
   {
       FooBar::init();
       std::cout << "FooBar::value = " << FooBar::value << std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. Make `value` a function in Foo:

   ```
   ...
   template<typename BarType>
   struct Foo
   {
       static const char * value() {
           return BarType::value;;
       }
   };

   using Bar = Derived<String>;
   using FooBar = Foo<Bar>;

   int main()
   {
       std::cout << "FooBar::value = " << FooBar::value() << std::endl;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Marking answer from @Barry as correct, since the 'why' was the most interesting part of the question. Your second solution is very analog to the original code. I think that is the best path and then reverting the changes will be easy when constexpr matures in VS. I'm adding a solution example to the question.